# How to bind the paused attribute of video element in vue.js to a function which can display/hide play button

Tags: html, vue.js, html5-video

We need to display the play button on video window if video is paused even if video buffer has enough data (this will happen in safari browser as Safari doesn't allow to play the videos without user intervention). I added event listener for pause event. The code is as given below (please note that this is .vue file)

```
<template>
    <div id="app" @keydown="handleKey($event)">
        <video ref="videoRef" src="" id="videoID" width="100%" v-on:pause="onVideoPause"></video>
        <div id="videoCC"></div>
        <button type="button" id="playVideo" v-on:click="onClickCallback"><img :src="require('@/assets/playVideo.png')"></button>
        <router-view tabindex="1"></router-view>
    </div>
</template>

export default {
    name: 'app',
methods: {
    onClickCallback: function () {
        console.log('onClickPlayback is called')
        let videoPlayer = player.instance()
        videoPlayer.play()
        videoPlayer.setLogLevel(4) // Set Log level to debug

        let playVideoBtn = document.getElementById('playVideo')
        // Video is playing. Hide the play button
        if (playVideoBtn.style.display === 'block') {
            playVideoBtn.style.display = 'none'
        }
    },
    onVideoPause: function () {
        console.log('video is paused')
        let videoEl = document.getElementById('videoID')
        if ((videoEl.readyState > 2) && (videoEl.ended === false)) {
            console.log('video buffer has the data and video is not ended')
            document.getElementById('playVideo').style.display = 'block'
        }
    }
}
```

Basically when video is paused, onVideoPause() is getting called and if video is not ended, I am displaying the play button. In the click handler of the play button, I am playing the video and hiding the play button, But we faced below problem while testing with javascript console as below.

Video is playing. Used pause() from javascript console.

```
document.getElementById('video').pause()
```

Play button displayed but when we play() now from console, the button is not getting hidden as we are hiding the play button in click function of play button only. When I suggested we will add event listener for play also on video element, my reviewer suggested me to evaluate if we can do v-bind for the 'paused' attribute of video element.

If we can bind the paused attribute and if we can call a function when ever the value changes, we can do the hiding and display in that function. I am not able to figure out how can we bind the attribute and call the function whenever the value changes as v-bind only works with single expression. I am new to vue.js. Can any one please help me if this is possible with v-bind or with any other Vue directives?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> my reviewer suggested me to evaluate if we can do v-bind for the
>   'paused' attribute of video element

The answer to that question is "no". The video element is not a Vue instance, so its properties are not reactive. You must rely on events to detect changes. I demonstrated a two-way binding in my other answer. Here is another approach that is a little simpler in terms of coding.

```js
new Vue({
  el: 'main',
  data: {
    videoElement: null,
    paused: null
  },
  methods: {
    updatePaused(event) {
      this.videoElement = event.target;
      this.paused = event.target.paused;
    },
    play() {
      this.videoElement.play();
    },
    pause() {
      this.videoElement.pause();
    }
  },
  computed: {
    playing() { return !this.paused; }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<main>
  <video id="videoElement" controls poster="velocity-thumbnail.jpg"
  @canplay="updatePaused" @playing="updatePaused" @pause="updatePaused">
      <source src="https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/daniemon/demos/Velocity-Mobile.mp4" type="video/mp4" media="all and (max-width:680px)"> 
      <source src="https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/daniemon/demos/Velocity-Mobile.webm" type="video/webm" media="all and (max-width:680px)"> 
      <source src="https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/daniemon/demos/Velocity-SD.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/daniemon/demos/Velocity-SD.webm" type="video/webm">
      <p>Sorry, there's a problem playing this video. Please try using a different browser.</p>
  </video>

  <div class="controls">
    <button v-show="paused" @click="play">&#9654;</button>
    <button v-show="playing" @click="pause">&#9208;</button>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 5):

The general technique for two-way binding is:

1. in the `bind` phase, you install event listeners on the element to update the bound value
2. in the `update` phase, you move your bound value into the element.

In your case, you want to listen for the `playing` and `pause` events, and set a single `playing` variable appropriately. (`paused` is just `!playing`)

In the example below, I leave the controls on the video player and also add my own. You can use either control, and they stay in sync. (You should also remove the event listeners in the `unbind` phase. I didn't do that, because it's a little messy, and I wanted to keep the example short and simple.)

```js
new Vue({
  el: 'main',
  data: {
    playing: false
  },
  computed: {
    paused() {
      return !this.playing;
    }
  },
  directives: {
    play: {
      bind(el, binding, vnode) {
        el.addEventListener('playing', () => {
          vnode.context[binding.expression] = !el.paused;
        });
        el.addEventListener('pause', () => {
          vnode.context[binding.expression] = !el.paused;
        });
        vnode.context[binding.expression] = !el.paused;
      },
      update(el, binding) {
        if (el.paused) {
          if (binding.value) {
            el.play();
          }
        } else if (!binding.value) {
          el.pause();
        }
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    play() {
      this.playing = true;
    },
    pause() {
      this.playing = false;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<main>
  <video id="videoElement" controls poster="velocity-thumbnail.jpg" v-play="playing">
      <source src="https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/daniemon/demos/Velocity-Mobile.mp4" type="video/mp4" media="all and (max-width:680px)"> 
      <source src="https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/daniemon/demos/Velocity-Mobile.webm" type="video/webm" media="all and (max-width:680px)"> 
      <source src="https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/daniemon/demos/Velocity-SD.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/daniemon/demos/Velocity-SD.webm" type="video/webm">
      <p>Sorry, there's a problem playing this video. Please try using a different browser.</p>
  </video>

  <div class="controls">
    <button v-show="paused" @click="play">&#9654;</button>
    <button v-show="playing" @click="pause">&#9208;</button>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks. But my question is I need to display/hide play button based on paused attribute value. Not based on events. Paused attribute value will be false if video is playing & it will be true if video is not playing. But if I depend on Pause event listener, this event will be only triggered when the video is paused. So I need to add event listener for Play also. Instead of adding event listeners for play and pause, somehow if I can bind the paused attribute (not event), I can display/hide the button based on only one attribute instead of 2 event listeners. Hope my question is clear now.

Comment: There is an event listener for playing. The attribute is not reactive, so you cannot notice its changes except through the events. You can initialize your reactive variable from the paused attribute. See update to answer.

Comment: I've edited the `bind` event to make it clear that you are setting values based on the `paused` attribute.