# How to toggle button in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I have `play` and `pause` buttons.
How to make them toggle button(show/hide) in Vue?

This is my code so far,

```
<button @click="slickPause" v-if="">slickPause</button>
<button @click="slickPlay" v-else>slickPlay</button>

methods: {
    slickPause() {
      this.$refs.carousel.pause();
    },
    slickPlay() {
      this.$refs.carousel.play();
    }
```

please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bind the paused attribute of video element in vue.js to a function which can display/hide play button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49163182/how-to-bind-the-paused-attribute-of-video-element-in-vue-js-to-a-function-which)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a state for playing and toggle it

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    playing: false
  },
  methods: {
    slickPause() {
      // this.$refs.carousel.pause();
      this.playing = false
    },
    slickPlay() {
      // this.$refs.carousel.play();
      this.playing = true
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="slickPause" v-if="playing">slickPause</button>
  <button @click="slickPlay" v-else>slickPlay</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
<button @click="togglePlay">
  {{ isPlaying ? slickPause : slickPlay }}
</button>
```

```js
data() {
 return {
   isPlaying: false
 }
},
methods: {
  togglePlay() {
    let method = this.isPlaying ? pause : play;
    this.$refs.carousel[method]();
    this.isPlaying = !this.isPlaying 
  }
}
```